# Oracle - Trigger on table that updates different table - permission problem

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a weird problem. I am trying to write a TRIGGER that whenever DEPTNO in table SCOTT.DEPT is updated, then it updates my other Table ( SCOTT.EMP ) with a new DEPTNO.

I got a ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error, which is weird, because I'm logged in as system, I've made this table myself (create .. ) and my other trigger that I wrote is working properly.

Btw. Is this trigger written correctly?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trigger1
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF DEPTNO ON SCOTT.DEPT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE SCOTT.EMP 
     SET DEPTNO = :NEW.DEPTNO;
END;
```

Comment: What is the user/schema the trigger has been created under is? Is it SCOTT as well?

Comment: I am logged as System, I am a bit green and dont understand your question. How can I answer better?

Comment: never ever use system or sys users for any of your operations except for the ones directly related to database management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am logged as System"

You need to be careful with that. SYSTEM is an Oracle owned account, used for maintaining the database, so there are risks to changing its schema.

In this case you have created the trigger **in the SYSTEM schema** because you didn't prefix the trigger name with anything. Normally triggers are owned by the schema which owns the underlying table, in this case SCOTT.

I suggest you drop the trigger from the SYSTEM schema and re-create it in SCOTT.

Comment: Thank you. I used ````ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SCOTT;```` And it works. You are awesome

Comment: The trigger compiled but I've got 1 thing underlined ````UPDATE SCOTT.EMP```` Is my trigger implementation correct?